# Session variables, int and Object types within Spring Web Flow

Tags: java, session, spring-webflow

I'm going to save my entity ID into the session in one of action states:

```
<on-exit>
<evaluate expression="persistantService.saveOrUpdate(flowScope.entity)"/>
<evaluate expression="externalContext.sessionMap.put('entityId', flowScope.entity.Id)"/>
</on-exit>
```

Actually, entity.Id field - is int.

On the start of the flow i'm trying to get entityId from the session, if it exists, load it from storage, else - create new one. Here how I suppose to do it:

```
<decision-state id="test">
<if test="externalContext.sessionMap.contains('entityId')"
then="findExistingEntity"
else="creteNewEntity"/>
</decision-state>

<action-state id="findExistingEntity">
<evaluate expression="persistantService.findEntityById(externalContext.sessionMap.entityId)" 
result="flowScope.entity" />
</action-state>
```

The problem is that persistantService.findEntityById accepts int, but not Object or Integer that are taken from session.
How can I resolve it? How can I convert externalContext.sessionMap.entityId to int? 
Or probably there is another way, to test that entity is saved and load it from persistant storage?

Comment: why are you working with the sessionmap? i'd use the conversationscope. i'm actually not sure if that sessionmap stuff works in the flow xml

Answer (score 0):

i'd use the conversationScope

```
<on-exit>
    <evaluate expression="persistantService.saveOrUpdate(flowScope.entity)"/>
    <set name="conversationScope.entityId" value="flowScope.entity.Id"/>
</on-exit>
```

...

```
<decision-state id="test">
    <if test="conversationScope.entityId != null"  
    <!-- i'm not sure if that works you might put the test in a method in a bean and call that--!>
        then="findExistingEntity"
        else="creteNewEntity"/>
</decision-state>

<action-state id="findExistingEntity">
    <evaluate expression="persistantService.findEntityById(conversationScope.entityId)" 
        result="flowScope.entity" />
</action-state>
```